# Automapper, map a property that is on the many to many table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper, asp.net5

I'm working on an **.NET 5 API**.

I have to reply to a get call with a Json that serializes the **UnitDto** class and inside it the list of all the **InstDto** class but I need a property that resides on the **UnitInst** object (the table many to many)

My classes:

```
public class Unit
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UnitInst> UnitInsts { get; set; }
}

public class Inst
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UnitInst> UnitInsts { get; set; }
}

public class UnitInst
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long UnitId { get; set; }
    public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; }
    public long InstId { get; set; }
    public virtual Inst Inst { get; set; }
    public string IPv4 { get; set; } // the property that is important
}
```

My dto's

```
public class UnitDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<InstDTO> Insts { get; set; }
}

public class InstDTO
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string IPv4 { get; set; } // I need serialize this property in my response json
}
```

I map in this way and it's ok but i can't retrive IPv4 property from UnitInst class (the many to many table)

```
CreateMap<Unit, UnitDto>()
    .ForMember(dto => dto.Insts, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.UnitInsts.Select(y => y.Inst).ToList()))
    .PreserveReferences();
```

How can I solve?

Comment: Some information is missing here. There are `Inst` and `Instrument`, also `UnitInst` and `UnitInstrument`. Are those pairs of the same thing?

Comment: @Dialecticus sorry, my mistake i have updated the question, only Inst class exists here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would create 2 maps (`Unit` -> `UnitDto` and `Inst` -> `InstDto`) and use the `Select` trick you've shown. But that is applicable only when the join entity has no additional data, which is not the case here.

So you need to map the join entity collection directly:

```
CreateMap<Unit, UnitDto>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Insts, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.UnitInsts)); // <-- no Select
```

and create additional map `UnitInst` -> `InstDto`:

```
cfg.CreateMap<UnitInst, InstDTO>()
    .IncludeMembers(src => src.Inst) // needs `Inst` -> `InstDTO` map
    .ForMember(dst => dst.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Inst.Id));
```

Here AutoMapper [IncludeMembers](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html#includemembers) is used to map the `Inst` members specified by the regular `Inst` -> `InstDTO` map, and the target `Id` property is mapped explicitly because both source and "included" objects have a property with the same name, in which case the source have priority, but you want `Id` to be `Inst.Id` or `InstId`.

Finally the `Inst` -> `InstDTO` map:

```
CreateMap<Inst, InstDTO>()
    .ForMember(dst => dst.IPv4, opt => opt.Ignore());
```